# How to change the datatype of an existing tree in SML?

Tags: recursion, tree, sml, smlnj

I need to solve this problem. I really have no clue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I guess a traversal needs to be done but I have no idea how to attack this problem. Thanks in advance.

Consider again the following 1st datatype definition of a binary tree:

```
datatype 'a tree = Empty | Node of { lT: 'a tree, key: 'a, rT: 'a tree }
```

After you have written some functions for binary trees defined by this datatype, you would like to test
them. You search online for test cases and find a database with binary trees that are actually defined
using the following 2nd datatype:

```
datatype 'a tree = Empty | Node of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree
```

Write a function "convert" that takes as input a binary tree of the second datatype and converts it into the
equivalent tree of the first datatype.

Comment: Here's a hint: write down the type of this `convert` function. It takes one type and returns another. Then think what can you do with the type it receives.

Comment: BTW, I suggest you edit the names in the second type, so that it's easier to compile the code: `datatype 'a their_tree = TheirEmpty | TheirNode of 'a their_tree * 'a * 'a their_tree`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, you need to traverse the tree, which can be elegantly achieved in SML by using pattern matching.  You will want to case on the input tree, if it is Empty then simply return Empty.  If it is a Node, then you will want to recursively convert the left and right subtrees and place those results into the other representation.  This shouldn't require any more than 4 lines of code.